# What does XA in "X/Open XA" stand for?

Tags: distributed-transactions, xa

I know what does XA mean but I'm curious on what it stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Common abbreviation for 'eXtended Architecture'.
>
> In database terms, this was used to describe a specific architecture of distributed systems that supported 'confirmed distributed transactions' using mechanisms such as two phase commit. IIRC, first appeared shortly after the release of the SQL-86 spec, but before SQL-89 (and therefore before SQL-92).

See http://www.orafaq.com/usenet/comp.databases.oracle.misc/2004/04/23/0521.htm

Answer (score 2):

From the [XAP-PT specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9695999099/toc.pdf):

```
This document is a CAE Speciﬁcation (see above). It deﬁnes the X/Open ACSE/Presentation
(XAP) programming interface Transaction Processing extension (XAP-TP).
X/Open has already deﬁned an ACSE/Presentation (XAP) programming interface (see
Referenced Documents), which provides for access to the ISO OSI protocol stack at the upper
two layers (Association Control Service Element and Presentation) of the OSI 7-layer model.
```

Seems to me that XA stands for **X/ACSE**